# Is there an audio renderer?

Tags: audio

I wanted to know if there is a sound render like the renderers of 3d modeling software (vray ,  cycles etc).

I would like to experiment with sound in a controlled environment

if it does not exist which is what makes it difficult to create an audio renderer?

Comment: do you mean something that simulates a room?  like you specify the geometry of a space and the renderer tells you what the reverberation sounds like?  otherwise i just don't have the foggiest idea of what you mean. $$ $$ what function does an "**audio renderer**" do?

Comment: I refer to a simulator that simulates all the properties of sound (absorption, diffraction, reflection) as in real life.
have a virtual speaker and a virtual listener and that the sound generated by the virtual speaker goes through the (absorption, diffraction, reflection, etc.) and reaches the listener and hear in my headphones.

Comment: i haven't understood "*absorption, diffraction,* and *reflection*" to be properties of sound.  they are properties of spaces, structures, and devices that have an effect upon sound.

Answer (score 2):

"Sound renderers" do exist, and some are very good: have a look at the [research of Nikunj Raghuvanshi](http://www.nikunjr.com/). For an introduction to their rendering method:

Nikunj Raghuvanshi, Rahul Narain and Ming C. Lin, **Efficient and Accurate Sound Propagation Using Adaptive Rectangular Decomposition**, *IEEE Transactions on Visualization and Computer Graphics(TVCG), 15(5), 2009.*

Abstract:

> Accurate sound rendering can add significant realism to complement
>   visual display in interactive applications, as well as facilitate
>   acoustic predictions for many engineering applications, like accurate
>   acoustic analysis for architectural design. Numerical simulation
>   can provide this realism most naturally by modeling the underlying
>   physics of wave propagation. However, wave simulation has
>   traditionally posed a tough computational challenge. In this paper, we
>   present a technique which relies on an adaptive rectangular
>   decomposition of 3D scenes to enable efficient and accurate simulation
>   of sound propagation in complex virtual environments. It exploits the
>   known analytical solution of the Wave Equation in rectangular domains,
>   and utilizes efficient implementation of Discrete Cosine Transform on
>   the GPU to achieve at least a hundred-fold performance gain compared
>   to a standard Finite Difference Time Domain (FDTD) implementation with
>   comparable accuracy, while also being an order of magnitude more
>   memory-efficient. Consequently, we are able to perform accurate
>   numerical acoustic simulation on large, complex scenes in the
>   kilohertz range. To the best of our knowledge, it was not previously
>   possible to perform such simulations on a desktop computer. Our work
>   thus enables acoustic analysis on large scenes and auditory display
>   for complex virtual environments on commodity hardware.

The paper [has its own website](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/propagation/). The manuscript version of the paper there is missing some prose, so preferably get the paper from the [first link](http://www.nikunjr.com/).

Siemens, for example, advertises acoustics simulation as part of their [computer aided engineering solutions](https://www.plm.automation.siemens.com/global/en/products/simulation-test/cae-simulation.html).

Answer (score 1):

Graphics rendering is the process of **projecting** a three dimensional description of a simulated world of objects into a photographic **plane** (the viewport) which represents the observers capturing point in the world.

In an analogous manner, the process of calculating the acoustic sound pressure, that results from a simulated audio in a three dimensional world, at the specified positions of capturing microphones, can be called as audio rendering.

And this is the essence behind the 3D audio-fx in computer games for example.

Such a rendering inevitably requires the consideration of the room or space geometry and all sorts of reverberations, echoes, transmisisons, absorptions, shadows, etc.. in addition to many other **effects** that should be taken into account.

Comment: i would think that such rendering also requires some knowledge about the listener, such as *head-related transfer functions* (HRTF), *interaural spacing*, and the position and facing orientation of the listener within the space geometry.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson alright then you are placing the mics into your ears ;-)